# REGEX - Pequenos detalhes que não casam

Tags: regex

Tenho essa expressão:

```regex
(?:[ \t]*[a-z][)]\s*)?([^\r\n<]+(?:(?:\r?\n(?!\s*[a-z][)])|<(?!br\s*\/?>(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>)*\s*(?:\s+[a-z][)]|\s*$)))[^\r\n<]*)*)(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*
```

Que casa com esse texto e retira as letras a),b),c),d),e) e os `<brs>` só do fim:

```html
<strong>Preencha</strong> a lacuna e assinale a alternativa correta. <br /><br />
I - capacitação técnico-profissional: Comprovação do licitante de possuir em seu quadro permanente, na data prevista para entrega da proposta, ________________, detentor de atestado de responsabilidade técnica por execução de obra ou serviço de características semelhantes, limitadas estas exclusivamente às parcelas de maior relevância e valor significativo do objeto da licitação, vedadas as exigências de quantidades mínimas ou prazos máximos (Lei 8.666/1993 Art N° 30).<br />
<br />
a)<strong>profissional</strong> de nível superior<br />
b)profissional de nível superior ou outro devidamente reconhecido pela entidade competente<br />
c)profissional capacitado<br />
d)profissional de nível minimamente técnico<br />
e)profissional especializado no objeto da <strong>licitação</strong>
```

Atualmente ela sai assim:

```html
strong>Preencha</strong> a lacuna e assinale a alternativa correta.<br /><br />
I - capacitação técnico-profissional: Comprovação do licitante de possuir em seu quadro permanente, na data prevista para entrega da proposta, ________________, detentor de atestado de responsabilidade técnica por execução de obra ou serviço de características semelhantes, limitadas estas exclusivamente às parcelas de maior relevância e valor significativo do objeto da licitação, vedadas as exigências de quantidades mínimas ou prazos máximos (Lei 8.666/1993 Art N° 30).
a)<strong>profissional</strong> de nível superior
profissional de nível superior ou outro devidamente reconhecido pela entidade competente
profissional capacitado
profissional de nível minimamente técnico
profissional especializado no objeto da <strong>licitação</strong>
```

Pode ser vista aqui https://regex101.com/r/MDstG4/4

Porém como visto nesse link, ao inserir alguma tag de formatação no inicio da pergunta, ou no começo das respostas não casa. Veja o `<strong>` como retorna cortado, no inicio da pergunta e a letra a) que é inclusa na primeira resposta. Deveria vir limpa, como as outras respostas.

**Lembrando que a pergunta, e cada resposta estou pegando separadamente para inserir em um campo no banco de dados.**

A tentativa é pegar:

1. Pegar tudo até o a) e excluir todos `brs` só do fim.
2. Pegar da letra a),b)... até a próxima letra excluindo todos `brs` só do fim.

Código ASP. To usando assim, porque hora são 4 respostas, hora 5.

```
questao=Request.Form("editor")

Set re = New RegExp'RegEx
re.Global = true
re.IgnoreCase = true
re.Pattern = "(?:[ \t]*[a-z][)]\s*)?([^\r\n<]+(?:(?:\r?\n(?!\s*[a-z][)])|<(?!br\s*\/?>(?:\s*<br\s*\/?>)*\s*(?:\s+[a-z][)]|\s*$)))[^\r\n<]*)*)(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*"    

Set matches = re.Execute(questao)
If (matches.Count) Then

    For m = 1 To matches.Count - 1

    '4 respsotas
    if (matches.Count-1)=4 then
        pergunta=matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_a=matches(1).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_b=matches(2).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_c=matches(3).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_d=matches(4).SubMatches(0)
    end if

    '5 respostas
    if (matches.Count-1)=5 then
        pergunta=matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_a=matches(1).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_b=matches(2).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_c=matches(3).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_d=matches(4).SubMatches(0)
        resposta_e=matches(5).SubMatches(0)
    end if

    Next
End If
Set matches = Nothing
Set re = Nothing
```

Comment: A minha opinião, ainda que não diretamente relacionada com resolver o problema, é que você está a resolver o problema de forma errada. Se é você que constroi esse html, então adicione etiquetas adicionais para facilitar a captura dos elementos. Parsing especifico de html, especialmente para casos mais elaborados tipo o seu, regex regra geral não é o caminho. Existem parsers de html precisamente por esse motivo.

Comment: Não sou eu, são usuários que nada entendem sobre isso.

Comment: Na verdade, estou quase chegando na solução, falta só esses detalhes que não consigo ajustar.

Comment: Que tal assim? https://regex101.com/r/Xoyimh/1

Comment: @MarceloUchimura parece perfeito, mas no count maches no asp não funciona. Vou colocar o código na pergunta pra vc ver.

Comment: @Rod Esta regex satisfaz? `(?![a-z]?\)).+(?=<br\s*\/)` E a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MDstG4/5). Vi que ASP é muito similar ao VBA, se necessário posso criar um exemplo de VBA... Pois não conheço ASP

Comment: @danieltakeshi parece perfeita, vou testar. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: to vendo aqui que a pergunta pega dois maches. teria que ser um maches, independente das quebras de linha que tiver.

Comment: Somente a pergunta? As opções em letras podem ser separadas?

Comment: @danieltakeshi Sim, um mach para a pergunta, independente de quantos brs tiverem no meio, só excluir os do fim, e um mach para cada letra, podendo também ter brs no meio, mas não no fim. Porque ai consigo pegar separadamente e gravar no banco. Valeu por responder meu amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Por que você não facilita o código, montando mais de uma expressão regular, mais simples?

Para capturar os itens da questão,

```
Dim patternQuestao = "[a-z]\)(.+?)\<br\s+\/\>"
```

Para capturar o título da questão,

```
Dim patternTitulo = "((.|[\r\n])+?)[a-z]\)"
```

E para retirar a quebra de linha,

```
Dim patternQuebra = "\<br\s+\/\>\s*$"
```

Por exemplo, seu código poderia virar o seguinte:

```
Set r = new RegExp
r.IgnoreCase = True

'--- coleta o titulo
Dim titulo
r.Pattern = patternTitulo
r.Global = False
Set matchQuestao = r.Execute(entrada)
If Not matchQuestao Is Null And matchQuestao.Count = 1 Then
    titulo = matchQuestao.Matches(0).Submatches(0)
End If

'--- retira as quebras do titulo
r.Pattern = patternQuebra
r.Global = True
titulo = r.Replace(titulo, "")

'--- coleta as questoes
Dim resposta_a, resposta_b, resposta_c, resposta_d, resposta_e
r.Pattern = patternQuestao
r.Global = True
r.Multiline = True
Set matchQuestoes = r.Execute(entrada)
If Not matchQuestoes Is Null And matchQuestoes.Count > 0 Then
    With matchQuestoes
        resposta_a = .Matches(0).Submatches(0)
        resposta_b = .Matches(1).Submatches(0)
        resposta_c = .Matches(2).Submatches(0)
        resposta_d = .Matches(3).Submatches(0)
        If matchQuestoes.Count > 4 Then
            resposta_e = .Matches(4).Submatches(0)
        End If
    End With
End If

'---- retira as quebras de linha das questoes
r.Pattern = patternQuebra
r.Global = True
resposta_a = r.Replace(resposta_a, "")
resposta_b = r.Replace(resposta_b, "")
resposta_c = r.Replace(resposta_c, "")
resposta_d = r.Replace(resposta_d, "")
resposta_e = r.Replace(resposta_e, "")
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, mas estou desitindo, venho insistindo nisso tem muito tempo. Não consigo de jeito nenhum. Seu código tem varios problemas com o asp 3. A ideia é ótima, mas não consegui acertar, modifiquei quase tudo pra tentar rodar e não cosegui.

Comment: além disso, o br só pode ser retirado no fim da regra, os do meio não.

Comment: por exemplo a que captura o titulo https://regex101.com/r/fn1d7g/4

Comment: se eu conseguir uma regex que tira os brs só do fim da string acho que reosolvo o que quero fazer.

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

Esta expressão regular resolve a questão de exemplo: `(?:[a-z]\))?([\s\S]+?)(?:<br\s*\/>\s*)?(?=[a-z]{1}\)|$)`

Em que o grupo 1 de cada match é capturado sem as letras de início das alternativas.

> Com somente global de opção (/g), sem multiline (/m)

Em que a demo no Regex101 pode ser vista [neste link](https://regex101.com/r/MDstG4/9) e o Debuggex [neste link](https://www.debuggex.com/r/P8rBw66GLrWKVJwD)

### Explicação

Corresponde a todos os caracteres antes de `[a-z]\)`, por exemplo: a), b), ..., z), ou do fim da string `$`.

Que comece ou não com `[a-z]\)` e termine ou não com `<br />`, ambos fora do grupo 1 de captura.